# Angular and Internet Explorer 11 - Inputs Not Working Correctly

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm having severe issues with inputs using ng-model in IE (11 and all previous versions,) but everything is working correctly in all other browsers. This issue was first observed last week. We have made no updates to this section of our application and heard no reports of users having this issue prior to last week.

We are running Angular 1.4.3.

Basically, inputs like this one:

```
<input data-ng-model="answer.value"></input>
```

Are not correctly updating the model. It looks like an issue with onChange or onFocus events - the inputs never lose their ng-pristine and ng-untouched classes. They are properly displaying the initial value from the model but any updates made by the user simply fail to save. We've experimented with adding a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />` tag to our head to no avail. Removing all validations from the inputs makes no difference. There are no console errors or alerts.

Comment: `inputs` dont need a closing `</input>` tag. Just make it self closing `<input data-ng-model="answer.value" />` May not be the issue... but it might?!

Comment: It does not work as a self-closing tag either.

Comment: I had the same symptoms of inputs not updating ng-model in IE only, but not sure whether the root cause was the same. I our app the problem was that one of the divs up the tree had `disabled` attribute set on it.

Comment: @LeviMorris Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: do you have types on your inputs?  like <input type="text" ng-model="answer.value"></input>?

Comment: @Wade Our solution was to stop supporting IE entirely - it was a small fraction of our userbase, and after investing multiple developer days into this we decided that the correct course of action was to drop the browser like a bad habit.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff All of our inputs are typed. My best guess is that this has to do with the terrible handling of onFocus events in IE, but we decided it wasn't worth the amount of time it would take to fully audit that and instead dropped IE support entirely.

Comment: @LeviMorris did you use iframes when you saw this error?

Comment: @NarainMittal Nope, no iFrames are in use here.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a parent component, and a child input.

The parent component had a poor choice of Angular binding attribute; I called the attribute "`disabled`". `disabled` was a bad choice of *custom* attribute name because that is a *standard* attribute for many  HTML elements.

**When I changed the custom attribute name to "`custom-disabled`", the child inputs started responding.**

Internet Explorer interpreted some ancestor `disabled` attribute to mean all descendants should be disabled; therefore my angular input `ng-model`, `ng-change`, `ng-blur`, `ng-focus` were not working.

I should've known: when I asked `$('input').is(':disabled')`, the result was `true`. I ignored this because the `input` element itself didn't have the `disabled` attribute; only an ancestor element did!

Answer (score 1):

I had simillar problem and solution seems to be easy. If you have code similar like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <table ng-disabled="formToggle">
        ...
        <input ng-model="form.name" />
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

IE10, IE11 won't check fields and won't set their pristine dirty values on form (other browsers works ok). Just remove ng-disabled (from table in this case and in other case from parent element) and it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately in our setup there is no actual <form> element. I'll try to experiment with your reasoning if I get the chance - at this point it's been almost a year since we formally dropped IE support and we're very happy not supporting it!